# What is the best way to store Symfony project on github?

Tags: php, git, symfony, github

I've created a Symfony project and pushed it to the github. Now I want to get it from github on another machine.

The problem is that there are a lot of files/folders in Symfony's .gitignore file by default, so my application is broken after 'git clone' command.

I would like to know, what is the best way/practice to store and retrieve Symfony application on/from github. What are the common steps to do it?

Comment: You should to do `$ composer install` command after git clone first. Also check official docs [How to deploy Symfony app](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html)

Comment: How does your `.gitignore` get broken? When you `clone` it creates a new, empty directory.

Comment: you can check out http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/workflow/new_project_git.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to [download and install Composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/) on your server.
Keep your .gitignore as default and install your vendors on each cloning.

If your deployment isn't recurrent, you can do it manually by use :

```
composer install
```

after each cloning .

If you deploy recurrently or just if you want, you can automate your deployment using [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) tasks for Symfony2